# How to check hook value after it has been change in the jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I am having a toggle button in the functional component which changes the hook from true to false and vice versa. I am trying to write a test for that functionality and in the end, I want to expect that the hook has changed. This is so far what I have done:

Toggle button:

```
 <input
   type="checkbox"
   name="checkbox-onoff"
   onChange={() => setEnableDateFormatting(!enableDateFormatting)}
   checked={enableDateFormatting}
   id="policy-switcher"
   value={enableDateFormatting}
 />
```

And I have a test case where I simulate the onChange event after which the enableDateFormatting hook has been changed from false to true. How can I access that hook and check its state?
For example: expect(wrapper.find('#policy-switcher').props.value).toEqual(true);

```
it('Enable/Disable date formatting', () => {
    const toggleBtn = dateFormatModal.find('#policy-switcher');

    // simulate onChange function on toggle button
    toggleBtn.simulate('change');

    dateFormatModal.update();

    expect(toggleBtn.props.value).toEqual(true) --> I am getting undefined instead;
  });
```

Comment: This works:

`
it('Enable/Disable date formatting', () => {
    const toggleBtn = dateFormatModal.find('#policy-switcher');

    // simulate onChange function on toggle button
    toggleBtn.simulate('change');

    expect(dateFormatModal.find('#policy-switcher').prop('value')).toEqual(true);

    // simulate onChange function on toggle button
    toggleBtn.simulate('change');
  
    expect(dateFormatModal.find('#policy-switcher').prop('value')).toEqual(false);
  });
`